# How can I account for fixed pos. overlay on page down?

Tags: javascript, css, web

Say I have a navbar `div`, which is at a `fixed` position at the top of the page, and the rest of the web page scrolls up beneath it.

How can I tell the page that when the user presses Page Down or the spacebar to scroll down one page height, that the distance that the page scrolls takes into account the visible content area, so that the first sentence of the next “page” doesn't end up hidden under the navbar. That is, I want it to scroll (pseudocode) `browser_height - height_of_navbar`

A simpler CSS solution would be preferred, if possible, but I'm open to a JavaScript solution, if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a margin-top to the body.

CSS:

```
BODY {
    margin-top: <navbar height + offset here>
}
```

Comment: I tested this; doesn't work. Poster wants the content at the bottom of the page to be hidden under the fixed nav bar. This still seems to occur even with margin added to the body, at least in Chrome. The browser still considers the margin part of the "page" that should get scrolled.

Comment: Use padding not margin

Answer (score 0):

Add these styles:

```
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

That will prevent the entire page from scrolling.

Add these styles to your content (change `100` to your navbar's height):

```
.content {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

That will place the scroll bar on the content rather than the window.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/021rczo8/)